# I am trying to Import Google Finance info to Google Sheets

Tags: xml, google-sheets, web-scraping, google-sheets-formula, yahoo-finance

I am trying to import some date from Yahoo Finance to Google Sheets, but I am facing some issues.

The information I am trying to receive is from this link:

https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/GPRO/financials?p=GPRO and the value I want to get back is **Net Income** for 2018 which is: "**-109,034**"

I was trying really hard in the last 6 hours, and started from the basic to retrieve whole info so I can filter it down.. but I wasn't successful

Below is the last code I write, but still doesn't return me anything..

```
=IMPORTXML("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/GPRO/financials?p=GPRO","//*[@id=""mrt-node-Col1-1-Financials""]")
```

If someone can assist would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change @id=""mrt-node-Col1-1-Financials"" for @id='mrt-node-Col1-1-Financials'

Answer (score 0):

You can import the data from the website with [IMPORTHTML](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093339?hl=en) instead and then find the Net Income value with a [VLOOKUP](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093318?hl=en).

`=IMPORTHTML("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/GPRO/financials?p=GPRO", "table", 1)`

`=VLOOKUP("Net Income", A:E, 2)` The number 2 was selected because it is the result related to **2018**.

Comment: Hello, Thanks for the feedback. For using importHTML, i am getting #N/A.. :(

Comment: @user1483138 Could you show me what you have on your formula?

Comment: try to paste this in any google sheet: `=INDEX(IMPORTXML("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/GPRO/financials?p=GPRO","//*[@id]"))` . I am getting all the div's with "id" but cannot identify the net income within those..

Comment: @user1483138 why are you not using the solution I provided?

Comment: The formula is not working.